# Consecutive transformations in SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm an SQL newbie, so there might be a standard recipe for the question I'm about to ask or it might already have been answered. I don't know the proper nomenclature for describing the type of operation I'm after, so I didn't know what to search for.

So, back to my problem: I have a table with transformations of an ID column that is used in other tables. It does include consecutive transformations, possibly several chained such transformations. All rows have a date stamp. Here's a toy sample:

```
|---------|-------|------------|
| from_id | to_id |       date |
|---------|-------|------------|
|    1001 |  2001 | 2019-01-01 |
|    1002 |  2002 | 2019-01-01 |
|    1003 |  2003 | 2019-02-02 |
|    2001 |  3001 | 2019-03-03 |
|    2002 |  3002 | 2019-03-03 |
|    3001 |  4001 | 2019-04-04 |
|---------|-------|------------|
```

From this data I would like to create two tables:

1. A table linking every from_id to its last to_id. For my toy example i want the following:

```
|---------|-------------|
| from_id | final_to_id |
|---------|-------------|
|    1001 |        4001 |
|    1002 |        3002 |
|    1003 |        2003 |
|    2001 |        4001 |
|    2002 |        3002 |
|    3001 |        4001 |
|---------|-------------|
```

2. I also want a table with all linked ID:s, in both directions. For my toy example:

```
|------|------|
| id_1 | id_2 |
|------|------|
| 1001 | 2001 |
| 1001 | 3001 |
| 1001 | 4001 |
| 1002 | 2002 |
| 1002 | 3002 |
| 1003 | 2003 |
| 2001 | 1001 |
| 2001 | 3001 |
| 2001 | 4001 |
| 2002 | 1002 |
| 2002 | 3002 |
| 2003 | 1003 |
| 3001 | 1001 |
| 3001 | 2001 |
| 3001 | 4001 |
| 3002 | 1002 |
| 3002 | 2002 |
| 4001 | 1001 |
| 4001 | 2001 |
| 4001 | 3001 |
|------|------|
```

These two results could of course be combined into just one table, where the relevant rows for result 1 is just highlighted by a flag.

So, how do I do this in SQL? Any help deeply appreciated. Note that I don't know how many steps the longest chain of transformations contains, but I do know that it's increasing from day to day.

Comment: I don't understand the logic behind the relationships in your two expected output tables.

Comment: Check if your dbms supports [recursive cte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_and_recursive_queries_in_SQL).

Comment: You example data suggest that the last digit determines a group it belongs to. Is that also the case for your real data?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm using Snowflake, which has its own dialect based on SQL-92 ANSI. I've added a Snowflake tag.

Comment: @Serg Yes, it does.

Comment: @J.D. No, it is not the case for the real data. Just made the example up that way in order to be able to sort out all combinations in my head. I realize it is misleading, sorry.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Most likely because the first expected output was wrong. I have corrected it.

Comment: Then try recursive CTE as it is understood by Snowflake. Ask another question describing the problems if any with the CTE query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Gordon said, you need a recursive CTE, which embodies a particular kind of fixed-point recursion. I think it's easiest to think about this in two phases:

1. Complete the transitive closure; then
2. Use this to produce the result you want.

We'll use the CTE for the first part. The CTE has two clauses, separated by a "union all". The first clause is run once to prime them pump; the second one runs repeatedly until it produces no output (or exceeds the allowable number of iterations). Each time the second clause runs, two things happen:

- The results are *appended* to the CTE results; and
- The results *replace* the "working" value of the CTE within the CTE.

With that in mind, here's a CTE that computes the transitive closure query. It makes a few important assumptions:

- There are no cycles in your ID chains;
- The IDs are always increasing; and
- The dates are irrelevant.

Here's the code:

```
with cte as (
  select from_id, to_id
  from t
  union all
  select t1.from_id, t2.to_id
  from cte t1 join t t2 on t1.to_id = t2.from_id
)
select * from cte;
```

The first clause will generate your original table (minus the date column):

```
Round 1:
FROM_ID    TO_ID   
-------  -------  
   1001     2001  
   1002     2002  
   1003     2003  
   2001     3001  
   2002     3002  
   3001     4001
```

Then the second clause will use this result as the working table and join it with your original table. This will produce the next round:

```
Round 2:
FROM_ID    TO_ID   
-------  ------- 
   1001     3001  
   1002     3002  
   2001     4001
```

This will be appended to the result, but becomes the working table for the next round. So our third round gives us:

```
Round 3:
FROM_ID    TO_ID   
-------  ------- 
   1001     4001
```

The next round gives no results, which means no round will ever produce any new results—the CTE has reached a fixed-point. This is when the CTE terminates and gives us its final result:

```
FROM_ID    TO_ID   
-------  -------  
   1001     2001  
   1002     2002  
   1003     2003  
   2001     3001  
   2002     3002  
   3001     4001  
   1001     3001  
   1002     3002  
   2001     4001  
   1001     4001
```

We still need to do step 2, but from here it's relatively easy: your result is just the set of rows in the CTE with the maximal TO_ID for each FROM_ID. We'll add a little post-processing to the CTE:

```
with cte as (
  select from_id, to_id
  from t
  union all
  select t1.from_id, t2.to_id
  from cte t1 join t t2 on t1.to_id = t2.from_id
)
select from_id, max(to_id) as to_id
from cte
group by from_id;
```

Which gives us:

```
FROM_ID    TO_ID   
-------  ------- 
   1001     4001
   1002     3002
   1003     2003
   2001     4001
   2002     3002
   3001     4001
```

There we go. As Gordon pointed out, the other question should also be straightforward using the results of the same CTE:

```
with cte as (
  select from_id, to_id
  from t
  union all
  select t1.from_id, t2.to_id
  from cte t1 join t t2 on t1.to_id = t2.from_id
)
select from_id id_1, to_id id_1
from cte
union all
select to_id id_1, from_id id_1
from cte;
```

Comment: @Isasac Thanks for your thorough reply. I never used recursive CTE:s before so this was great for me. I ended up using your code with the extension of including a monotonically increasing counter column to account for more general ID transformations that do not necessarily increase in value.

Answer (score 2):

You need a recursive CTE for this purpose.  I think the simplest method is to go backwards from the most recent date:

```
with cte as (
      select t.to_id, t.from_id, t.from_id as terminal_id
      from toy t
      where not exists (select 1 from toy t2 where t2.from_id = t.to_id)
      union all
      select t.to_id, t.from_id, cte.terminal_id
      from cte join
           toy t
           on t.to_id = cte.from_id
     )
select *
from cte;
```

This produces half the rows.  For the other half, you can do:

```
select to_id, from_id, terminal_id
from cte
union all
select from_id, to_id, terminal_id
from cte;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Spot on. I ended up accepting the answer by @Isaac because it was more informative for a CTE newbie as myself.